# How could we get a variable value from GLSL?

Tags: c, glsl

I'm doing a project with a lot of calculation and i got an idea is throw pieces of work to GPU, but i wonder whether could we retrieve results from GLSL, if it is posible, how?

Comment: GLSL is not used for general-purpose GPU programming since hardware and software interfaces were developed for that purpose. Unless you need to program a GPU more than 6 years old, this probably isn't the question you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLSL does not provide outputs besides what is placed in the frame buffer.

To program a GPU and get results more conveniently, use [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) (NVidia only) or [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) (cross-platform).

Answer (score 3):

In general, what you want to do is use OpenCL for general-purpose GPU tasks. However, if you are insistent about pretending that OpenGL is not a rendering API...

[Framebuffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) make it relatively easy to render to multiple outputs. This of course means that you have to structure your processing such that what gets rendered matches what you want. You can render to 32-bit floating-point "images", so you have access to plenty of precision. The biggest difficulty is what I stated: figuring out how to structure your task to match rendering.

It's a bit easier when using transform feedback. This is the ability to write the output of the vertex (or geometry) shader processing to a [buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object). This still requires structuring your tasks into something like rendering, but it's easier because vertex shaders have a strict one-vertex-to-one-vertex mapping. For every input vertex, there is exactly one output. And if you draw `GL_POINTS`, it's not too difficult to use attributes to pass the data that changes.

Both easier and harder is the use of shader_image_load_store. This is effectively the ability to read/write from/to arbitrary images "whenever you want". I put that last part in quotes because there are lots of esoteric rules about data race conditions: reading from a value written by another shader invocation and so forth. These are *not* trivial to deal with. You can try to structure your code to avoid them, by not writing to the same image location in the same shader. But in many cases, if you could do that, you could just render to the framebuffer.

Ultimately, it's pretty much impossible to answer this question in the general case, without knowing what *exactly* you're trying to actually do. How you approach GPGPU through a rendering API depends greatly on exactly what you're trying to compute.